# Sporadic wrong urls

Tags: django, web-applications

We have an application running built on python/django. I get emails whenever there is a missing link (404) or a server error (500). I've noticed that i get a number of links that looks something like this:

```
Referrer: http://www.mywebsite.com/model/
Requested URL: /model/js/modernizr-1.7.min.cb14102011.js
User agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; GTB7.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
IP address: 41.2.246.84
```

The issue is the requested url. It requests the js file relative to the current dir, rather than the absolute dir. What makes it bizarre is that I can't reproduce it, and it happens a handful of times a day, even though there are many different users on the site. The consequence of the missing links also sometimes causes 500 errors, depending on the url (due to the django url structure I've defined for the application).

Has anybody seen this kind of issue before? Is there anything that I should check for that might resolve this issue?

**Edit:**
The js files are accessed through http://www.mywebsite.com/static/js/ The same configuration applies for css files. On further investigation it seems that the 'static' part gets dropped from the url.

**Edit (2)**
I made a mistake yesterday. not only does the {{ STATIC_URL }} not pull through as defined in the settings file, it is replaced with the current (relative) url. I.e, in the original post "model" should be "static", but its not replaced as such. I'm still at a loss as to why this happens.

Comment: I've had a really irritating recurring problem almost identical, it would more often do it for all the urls on the page bombing me with 404s for all the graphics files. Unfortunately, I have no solution for you. I changed my base template and the problem seems to have gone away and I haven't had a chance to dig through and find what the culprit was. Very interested in hearing the solution to this one myself :D

Comment: You have to explain your problem in more detail.

What should the request URLs be? How is your static file serving configured in Django?

Comment: maybe it is a bot that sends these requests. can it be?

Comment: Its not a bot, since all these requests happen behind user authentication. Even if the url was invoked directly it would get redirected to the login screen.

Comment: Two reasons why {{ STATIC_URL }} wouldn't show: You don't have the context processor set up in your `settings.py` file, or you're not rendering the templates with RequestContext.

Comment: The thing is, {{ STATIC_URL }} shows most of the time, just not sometimes. We have many users on our system, and I get say 10 instances a day. There are a lot more than 10 unique users hitting that url. Perhaps there is a coding error that causes django to bail and return from the call without the context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Dennis and Jordan. Your comments helped me a lot.

For my scenario I noticed the problems only happens on 1 url. Since many of the templates use the same base template. I ruled out a base template problem. I also checked the views of the  url to see that the context was added correctly (since without context the STATIC_URL variable might not pull through). All good.

I also only saw IE7 in the logs. When I looked at the template I noticed an extra closing " (ie class="bogus"" ). I think that extra quote messed up the template, and IE7 then had trouble rendering the rest of the template.

I've made the changes in production so am not 100% sure that I've fixed the problem, but I'll know within a day or so.

**Edit:**
The answer, I've realised, lies in the fact that if there is a coding problem (ie the server throws a 500), then the context doesn't get loaded correctly, and so the STATIC_URL doesn't get populated. This also means that each 500 error will have a corresponding 404 error for any files loaded from STATIC_URL

Comment: Good to hear how this went. Let us know if it seems to solve the problem.